# SQL CASE WHEN - NULL values returning unwanted rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two case statements running in the same select statement, but here is a simplified example:

```
SELECT t.Person,
       CASE WHEN t.Order LIKE 'Test Order 1 CHRG' THEN (SUBSTRING(t.Order PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',ord.Name),1)) END AS 'Order1' 
       CASE WHEN t.Order LIKE 'Test Order 2 CHRG' THEN (SUBSTRING(t.Order PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',ord.Name),1)) END AS 'Order2'
```

The results that I am getting are:

```
Name          Order1         Order2
======================================
Person A         4           NULL
Person A         NULL        3
Person B         2           NULL
Person B         NULL        3
Person C         1           NULL
Person C         NULL        5
```

Is there a way to ignore NULL value that is being produced by the CASE statements and have the query return only one row for each t.Name?  Like this:

```
Name          Order1         Order2
======================================
Person A         4           3
Person B         2           3
Person C         1           5
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add a `MAX` around your `CASE` expressions and the appropriate `GROUP BY` at the end of your query.

Comment: Brilliant!!  Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

(Now that I'm not on a Teams call) You're effectively doing a pivot here, which means you need to add some aggregation to eliminate the `NULL` values so that both values are on the same row. Filling in a few gaps, I suspect you therefore need:

```sql
SELECT t.Person,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.Order = 'Test Order 1 CHRG' THEN (SUBSTRING(t.Order PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',ord.Name),1)) END) AS Order1 --Don't use single quotes for aliases
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.Order = 'Test Order 2 CHRG' THEN (SUBSTRING(t.Order PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',ord.Name),1)) END) AS Order2 --You didn't need LIKE either, as there was no pattern
FROM dbo.Table1 t
     JOIN table2 ord ON t.id = ord.tid
GROUP BY t.Person;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Searched Case Statement** is the best fit to exclude **NULL** marker from the result set of the **Case Statement**.

Below is the base T-SQL syntax for it;

```
--Searched CASE expression:  
CASE  
     WHEN Boolean_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ]   
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ]   
END
```

[Detailed information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: That would be a case **expression** not **statement**.